# Refactoring 'if else' chain with many conditions

Tags: oop, if-statement, design-patterns, refactoring

I have code that looks something like this. An 'if else' chain with each one containing a long list of conditions of when that function should get called.

```
if (conditionA1() || conditionA2() && conditionA3() || ... && conditionAN()) {
    functionA();
}
else if (conditionB1() || conditionB2() && conditionB3() || ... && conditionBN() {
    functionB();
}
...
else if (conditionZ1() || conditionZ2() && conditionZ3() || ... && conditionZN()) {
    functionZ();
}
```

It looks like messy code which could get hard to maintain and was wondering if there is a good design pattern to refactor this.

Comment: Different languages have different facilities that can make this easier. From your example, this appears to be a C-based language, but could be C, java, javascript, C#... What language are you actually working in?

Comment: I am working in JavaScript but thought it was not specific to any language which is why I didn't put one. If you would do something for each language I would be interested to know the specifics for different ones

Comment: [Simplifying Conditional Expressions](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/simplifying-conditional-expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know two good tricks for dealing with long chains of conditionals.

The first is to create named variables to describe the combined conditions.

```
firstCompoundCondition = conditionA1() || conditionA2() && conditionA3() || ... && conditionAN();
secondCompoundCondition = conditionB1() || conditionB2() && conditionB3() || ... && conditionBN();
...
nthCompoundCondition = conditionZ1() || conditionZ2() && conditionZ3() || ... && conditionZN();

if (firstCompoundCondition) {
    functionA();
}
else if (secondCompoundCondition) {
    functionB();
}
...
else if (nthCompoundCondition) {
    functionZ();
}
```

The second - and this is kind of subtle and perhaps ultimately more powerful - is to eliminate the need for all the `else`s by structuring your code to return, ideally returning the result of the inner function, but simply returning inside the block can work as well.  This can mean extracting a function which doesn't look like much, but when all is said and done it's a lot cleaner.

```
firstCompoundCondition = conditionA1() || conditionA2() && conditionA3() || ... && conditionAN();
secondCompoundCondition = conditionB1() || conditionB2() && conditionB3() || ... && conditionBN();
...
nthCompoundCondition = conditionZ1() || conditionZ2() && conditionZ3() || ... && conditionZN();

if (firstCompoundCondition)  return functionA();
if (secondCompoundCondition) return functionB();
...
if (nthCompoundCondition)    return functionZ();
```

Comment: When you say 'This can mean extracting a function which doesn't look like much' what are you referring to that can get extracted?

Comment: Well, in the context of this question it's hard to show, but if for instance you had a block of code after the if-else block, then the if-else block would have to be extracted to ensure that the rest of the function executes.  And the original function would call the new function, followed by the rest of the function.

Answer (score 0):

If the conditions are all different, then nesting wouldn't be possible...however, what I find sometimes more readable is if I put each condition (or every two conditions) on a separate line, such as:

```
if (conditionA1() ||
    conditionA2() && conditionA3() ||
    ... &&
    conditionAN()) {
    functionA();
}
else if (conditionB1() ||
         conditionB2() && conditionB3() ||
         ... &&
         conditionBN() {
    functionB();
}
...
else if (conditionZ1() ||
         conditionZ2() && conditionZ3() ||
         ... && conditionZN()) {
    functionZ();
}
```

It looks kind of funny here, but usually if I do it with actual conditionals it looks better :)